# Physically, how does erection work?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, biophysics, biology

All articles I found explain a human male erection through biological mechanism. However I am still curious how such process can make the male sexual organ "stand up" during an erection.

From what I understand, during an erection, there are more blood in arteries but wouldn't it make it heavier and thus should not be standing up?

Comment: I've removed some comments that are attempting to answer the question. Please remember to post answers below and use comments to suggest/seek clarification or improvements. Thanks!

Comment: You might get better results from https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdrianHoward They might not be as careful talking about forces and physical mechanisms. Certainly this can be viewed from a physics / engineering sort of way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Think of it as being like a rubber balloon**

Take a long, empty, rubber balloon. It is floppy as the rubber does not have the stiffness to resist the force of gravity even given its small mass. Now fill it with air. The balloon will now stand up against the force of gravity despite now being heavier. The same effect is seen when filling the balloon with water (depending a little on the diameter) but the filled balloon is clearly *stiffer* than the empty balloon. This is similar to the human erection where more fluid is pumped into the penis.

The reason for the extra stiffness is that rubber (or human skin) under tension has different physical properties than when unstressed. It is now, effectively, stiffer and more able to resist gravity.

The direction the organ *points* is a consequence of that stiffness and what the organ is connected to. Just as a stiff balloon will hold its orientation if you hold one end of it, the stiff penis will hold the orientation determined by its connections to the body.

Comment: Note that this is true of any erectile tissue, whether human or not, male or not, sexual organ or not, etc.  It's probably only called "erectile tissue" because men dominated science in the 19th century, and that particular bit of erectile tissue makes itself obvious from time to time.